# how to reuse my <div> when i don't want to create another

Tags: html, css, block

I'm a somewhat beginning programmer, so i'm just making a practice website. On this website it shoud show blocks going down vertically in rainbow color order. I got the first column just fine, but i can't get the second column to actually move over to the right. I've tried relative and margin-left: 110; margin-top: 660;, but it's not working. Each box is 110 by 110.This is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "using namespace std;
<html>
    <body>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <style>
        div:first-child {
            width: 110;
            height: 110;
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
            background-color: red;
            border-radius: 25px;
        }

        div:nth-child(2) {
            width: 110;
            height: 110;
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
            background-color: orange;
            border-radius: 25px;
        }

        div:nth-child(3) {
            width: 110;
            height: 110;
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
            background-color: yellow;
            border-radius: 25px;
        }

        div:nth-child(4) {
            width: 110;
            height: 110;
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
            background-color: green;
            border-radius: 25px;
        }

        div:nth-child(5) {
            width: 110;
            height: 110;
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
            position: relative;
            margin-left: 0;
            background-color: blue;
            border-radius: 25px;
        }

        div:nth-child(6) {
            width: 110;
            height: 110;
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
            position: relative;
            margin-left: 0;
            background-color: purple;
            border-radius: 25px;
        }

        div:nth-child(1) {
            width: 110;
            height: 110;
            position: relative;
            margin-left: 110px;
            margin-top: 660px;
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
            background-color: red;
            border-radius: 25px;
        }
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's what your code actually looks like? Please, learn before you make, it makes the transition into to web design so much easier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem here is that your code has a lot of major errors in it, such as `width: 110` instead of `width: 110px`, as well as a lot of duplication. I've tidied up the code, but it's not clear what you actually want. I'm going to guess that you want the boxes in a horizontal line instead of in one column, so have added `float: left` into the mix as well. If that's not what you want, please clarify: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/yzGmj

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

    div {width: 110px; height: 110px; margin: 0px; border-radius: 25px; float: left;}
    div:first-child{background: red;} 
    div:nth-child(2){background: orange;}
    div:nth-child(3){background: yellow;}
    div:nth-child(4){background: green;}
    div:nth-child(5){background: blue;}
    div:nth-child(6){background: purple;}

</style>

</head>

<body>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ralph.m, thank you, you did take out a lot of my code... but you never did actually answer my question. my question is how to make a new column without having to write six more divs again and again. i don't know if this is possible, but i think it is. i hope my question now seems more clear

Comment: The question is a bit vague, hence the useless answer. You can write a little CSS that applies to many HTML elements, but not the other way around. You'd need to use something like JavaScript to create lots more divs on the fly. Otherwise, you need to add the divs into the HTML.

Comment: Thank's for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
div {display:inline-block;}
```